# Javascript based grid/data table

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, datagrid, datatable

Can someone please help me to shortlist a javascript based grid/data table. I have some RnD and list some of the grids.

[JS based grid components](http://zishanbilal.com/2012/08/28/js-based-grid-comparison/)

Java based frameworks that translate to js would could also be the choice.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) is probably the best choice. I have used it in many projects. I used jqGrid once... it was ok, but I think Datatables is superior